# main-address not returned from linkedin api

Tags: php, javascript, linkedin-api

I am using the javascript api to get the profile information from linkedin. For that the url passed is -

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people::(~):(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,main-address,headline,industry,summary,location,positions)
```

I am getting all the fields from this api except main-address. When I see the response in console it does not show the mainAddress field. 
There is an address to that linkedin profile.

Does there need to have other field other than main-address?

Any help appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: You need r_contactinfo member permission to get that field.  Do you know if you have requested the user for that permission?

Comment: will you please help me, how can I set the permission? I am using the linkedin api first time.

Comment: i got the solution, you can mention the scope in your script tag as -  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: ovdafyebkfex
  authorize: true
  scope: r_basicprofile r_contactinfo
</script>                                                            May this will help someone. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the main address of the authenticated LinkedIn user, take a look to the 'r_emailaddress' scope permission.